# .NET MAUI Error: "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup'"

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui

I am currently developing an application using .NET MAUI and I've encountered an issue that I'm unable to resolve. When I was debugging, I catched a strange exception when I navigated pages  on the android platform

The application has two tabs: Homepage and Selfhelp. After logging in, the user lands on the Homepage tab. However, when I attempt to navigate to any other page from the Homepage, the application throws the following error and subsequently crashes:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: ‘Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup'

This is my xaml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Views.Dashboard.HomePageDashboard"
             Title="HomePageDashboard">

<Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame 
                           
           Grid.Column="1"
           HeightRequest="40"
           WidthRequest="40"
           CornerRadius="20"
           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           IsClippedToBounds="True"
           Padding="0"
           >
                <Border BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColorLight}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ProfileImageLabel}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Micro" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GotoProfileCommand}"/>
                    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
                </Border>
                </Frame>
        </Grid>

    </Shell.TitleView>
 <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,30,0,0">
                <Label Text="Categories" FontSize="Subtitle" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black},Dark={StaticResource Gray400}}"/>
                <Frame CornerRadius="10" Margin="0,20,0,0">

                    <ListView x:Name="listCategories" Margin="-20,-10,-20,-20"
                          BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowHeight="60"
                          SeparatorColor="Gray" SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelectedlv}"
                          ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Grid x:DataType="model:HomePageListInfo">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HeightRequest="50"
                                           WidthRequest="50"
                           Source="{Binding ImageResource}"
                            />
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                           Style="{StaticResource CategoryListlabelStyle}"
                                           FontSize="18"
                           Text="{Binding ListViewItemDescription}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                            <Image Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <FontImageSource
                                    x:Name="fontimage"
                                            FontFamily="AwesomeSolid"
                                            Glyph="&#xf105;"
                                            Size="20"
                                            Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black},Dark={StaticResource White}}"/>
                                                </Image.Source>
                                            </Image>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Frame>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Interestingly, if I navigate to the Selfhelp tab and attempt to navigate to other pages from there, no error occurs and the application functions as expected.

I have tried to catch and handle the exception, but I am still unsure of the root cause of the problem. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Version: VS2022 17.6
I'm using .net 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have searched the exception message you mentioned and found the similar issue on the github about [MAUI application error due to entry element in background operation](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13762).

The frame will cause the exception such as `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.` in some conditions.

So you can try to use the [border in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) instead of using the frame.

Comment: Note for the next person finding this question - the issue is still present in .NET8 RC2.  Changing all <Frame> for <Border> elements resolves the issue for now.

Answer (score 3):

### I have found a way to fix it without switching to the Border

---

All you need to do is to add a layout to the Frame.

I used the Frame to decorate my Entry field but this caused the error "Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiAppCompatEditText"

So I added a VerticalStackLayout as a Content to the Frame and it worked

---

Before:

```
<Frame>
    <Entry .../>
</Frame>
```

Result - Error

---

After:

```
<Frame>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry .../>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Everything works well now
I hope it helped